# Best way to refactor complex dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, refactoring

#### TL;DR

I need a way to refactor a complex user dashboard with several objects and some complex data to display a accounting chart. My model and controller are pretty messy, so if anyone have some hints or suggestions, would i really appreciate it :)!

#### Long version:

Im currently working on an application that helps users to coordinate dinner clubs and all  related accounting. (A dinner club is where people in a group, take turns to cook for the rest and then you pay a small amount to participate. This is pretty normal in dorms and colleges where im from). When you login are you presented to a dashboard with all important information seperated in three blocks: the next dinner and option to registrate, the next dinner where you have to cook, and accounting overview like current debt, spendings etc.

This gets pretty messy: a lot of instance variables in my controller, and a lot of methods to present this view in my models.

So now to the real question: can anyone tell me any good hints, design patterns or general advice to help me refactor this code? I have read about presenters, service objects, decorators etc. but im not sure which to use and how?

Here is some examples of how bad it looks right now (a kitchen is the group of people that have dinner together):

```
# app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
def index
  @user = current_user
  @kitchen = @user.kitchen

  @upcoming_dinner_clubs = @user.upcoming_dinner_clubs # The next dinner clubs where the current user have to cook
  @users_next_dinner_club = @user.next_dinner_club # The first of upcoming_dinner_clubs
  @unpriced_dinner_clubs = @user.unpriced_dinner_clubs # Old dinner clubs where the user haven't specified a price yet

  # The next dinner club in the kitchen
  @next_dinner_club = @kitchen.next_dinner_club if @kitchen.next_dinner_club
  @todays_dinner_club = @next_dinner_club if @next_dinner_club && @next_dinner_club.date.today?
end
```

The view below shows some chart of the expenses and spendings of a user, rendered through javascript. My views are in haml.

```
# app/views/dashboard/_expenses.html.haml
%h2 Dit forbrug
  %p
    = t '.usage_html', expenses: number_to_currency(@user.last_month_expenses), spendings: number_to_currency(@user.last_month_spendings), results: number_to_currency(@user.last_month_results)
    = content_tag :div, "", id: "revenue_chart", class: "chart dashboard-chart", data: { chart: @user.usage_chart_data }
    = t '.results_html', results: number_to_currency(@user.total_results)
    = content_tag :div, "", id: "result_chart", class: "chart dashboard-chart", data: { chart: @user.result_chart_data }
```

Don't want you to bore you with all the details, and how the methods work, but this is the methods i have, only for displaying the expenses and spendings data in the view:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def last_month_expenses
  expenses_for((1.month + 1.day).ago, 1.day.ago)
end

def last_month_spendings
  spendings_for((1.month + 1.day).ago, 1.day.ago)
end

def last_month_results
  results_for((1.month + 1.day).ago, 1.day.ago)
end

def spendings_for(start_date, end_date, kitchen)
end

def expenses_for(start_date, end_date, kitchen)
end

def fee_for(start_date, end_date, kitchen)
end

def accounting_query_conditions(start_date, end_date, kitchen)
  {date: start_date..end_date, kitchen_id: kitchen.id}
end

def results_for(start_date, end_date)
  spendings_for(start_date, end_date) - expenses_for(start_date, end_date)
end

def total_fee(date = Date.today, kitchen = primary_kitchen)
end

def total_spendings(date = Date.today, kitchen = primary_kitchen)
end

def total_used_on_dinner_clubs(date = Date.today, kitchen = primary_kitchen)
end

def total_expenses(date = Date.today, kitchen = primary_kitchen)
end

def total_results(date = Date.today, kitchen = primary_kitchen)
  total_expenses(date, kitchen) - total_spendings(date, kitchen)
end
```

Comment: don;t you use decorators/presenters?

Comment: No but i definitely should :D! However im not sure how to implement this in the best way, and i thought that the example above was a good use case to learn it :).

Comment: Actually I see nothing to abstract in a decorator from the code you wrote there. I don't see any bad design neither. Your methods in your object make sense and the code is very readable. You abstract a lot of data in your controller within instance variables (which I wouldn't do) but why not...

Comment: What would you do? Chain the method calls to user?

Comment: yes, same way you already do when you write `@user.last_month_expenses`

Comment: I would prefer not to do that, because then i would have method chains like `@user.kitchen.next_dinner_club.chef.name` etc.

Comment: Also i would like to structure my code more, as i don't feel like this this belongs in my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's start with a rule and see how far it takes us:

**Only 1 instance variable in your controller**

In order to follow this rule, I think you'd likely want to create a UserDashboard object

```
class UserDashboard

  attr_reader :user
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def kitchen
    user.kitchen
  end

  def todays_club
    next_dinner_club if next_dinner_club && next_dinner_club.date.today?
  end

end
```

so, in your controller:

```
def index
  @dashboard = UserDashboard.new current_user
end
```

In this way, you are putting all of the logic about clubs and whatever onto the dashboard object, rather than in the controller or in the user object. It's a presenter-like pattern.

Comment: That makes sense! I will try to implement this and then update my question. However as this solves some of the problems, i still have a lot of code that only deals with the other half of my dashboard: accounting (expenses, spendings, etc.) and it's cluttering my user model. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: If they are only used in the dashboard, move them in here. If they are dealing with data of the user, I think it could make sense to leave there. I'd extract to dashboard object if only used in the dashboard.

Comment: I now created a "widget" class for each of the three widgets on the dashboard (they where a bit complicated so i thought that it would be good to split up the code). The three first methods (`last_month_...`) is now moved from the model to the `UsageWidget` class. This already looks much better. However i still feel that the remaining methods that handles user usage/expenses doesn't belong in the user class. None of them are calling any methods or using any attributes from the user expect the associated dinner_clubs to calculate a total price. Any suggestion for refactoring this?

Comment: Sure, create a UserDashboard class that takes in a user and adds those methods.